# Call a rails route into CSS (in haml)

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, haml

`= @photo.image.url` (in haml) will compile a url of an image depending on the view

I would like to use the image link produced by the tag in the CSS below- but that wont work.

```
#BG {
  background: url( HERE!!! ) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 400px;
}
```

I've tried javascript directly on the page to replace a hardwired image with a new image to test it out... but that didn't work. I've played with the code below and tried a lot of different versions of it.

```
:javascript
  document.getElementById('BG').style.background = "url('newimg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed"
```

Here is the Haml code where it will be used:

```
 #BG
  This div should have the image as a background
  %p= @photo.title
.container
  .jumbotron
```

I need a solution to get the image url into the background url

Comment: You can try this if you are using rails 4 `background-image: image-url("newimg.jpg")` and it should find `newimg` in your `assets/images/` folder

Comment: @Sontya, My question may have been confusing: newimg.jpg is an irrelevant image that I used to test the Javascript example I used

Comment: whatever name of your image file, how does it matter

Comment: Did you try inline style for #BG? Something like this `#BG{style: "background: url(#{@photo.image.url}) no-repeat"}`

Comment: The photos are all stored in the database. The css needs to be dynamic to the output generally called by: = @photo.image.url

Comment: @anpsmn I just tried "background: url(#{@photo.image.url}); It worked! Thank you!

Comment: @KTHero Cool. You must have tried in CSS so no need for `style`. I was mentioning the html tag `#BG` when you render it.

Comment: @KTHero Also you can self answer this question with what worked for you so that it can help others in future

Comment: @anpsmn, I was going to let you leave the answer so I'd up-vote it! I totally didn't imagine it working in CSS so I ended up trying some of the most ridiculous work arounds!

Comment: @KTHero Ok added that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpolate the value `@photo.image.url` and add it to the string

in HAML when rendering a tag

```
#BG{style: "background: url(#{@photo.image.url}) no-repeat"}
```

or

CSS

```
#BG {background: url("#{@photo.image.url}")}
```